# Auth0 Authentication in MERN Web Application

Tags: authentication, mern, auth0

**How auth0 and normal registration/create account works in web application simultaneously providing both options to user ?**

1. How does it works ?
2. What is the flow/approach to do the same in my MERN application ?

[image: Signin page of Udemy]

1. There are some other details which we take from user while creating account with the traditional way ?
2. But what with auth0 ?

This is my MERN project here -
[petcare-mohitjaiswal.netlify.app](https://petcare-mohitjaiswal.netlify.app)